# Expo-Router Tab Navigator, missing page transition and missing back button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

In my Expo app using `expo-router`, there should be 3 screens:

- `Home`
- `Settings`
- `User`

and 2 tabs

- `Home`
- `Settings`

This is my current file structure

```
app
├── (main)
│   ├── _layout.js
│   ├── home.js
│   ├── settings.js
│   └── user.js
```

I can configure the tab navigator in `_layout.js` to show only the 2 required tabs.

There is a button in `Settings` screen that brings you to the `User` screen with a `router.push('/user')`.

**Problems:**

1. On clicking this button, there is no sliding page transition/animation where the `User` screen slides in from the right side of the screen
2. There is no back button on the header of the `User` screen that brings u back to the previous screen `Settings`. Should the back button be created for you by default?

How can you configure the navigators/layouts to achieve this?

Thank you

**`layout.js`**

```
import { Tabs, useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

export default function Layout() {

  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Tabs>
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="home"
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />

        <Tabs.Screen
          name="settings"
          options={{ title: "Settings" }}
        />

        <Tabs.Screen
          name="user"
          options={{
            title: "User",
            href: null,
            tabBarStyle: { display: "none" },
          }}
        />
      </Tabs>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set `screenOptions={{animation: "none", headerShown: true}}` on your `<Stack></Stack>` component inside `_layout.jsx` `!!!JSX!!!`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).